# jquery clone() for dynamic data not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I am stuck with a rather weird problem here. My idea is simple enough. I have a social media website where my users make 'postings' just like on facebook. Now in order to output all the posts on the home page, I created a simple php page which echos JSON encoded data. The Json Data looks like this:

```
{  "posts" : [
         {"post_id" : "1", "user_id" : "1", "post_text" : "Hello World 1"},
         {"post_id" : "2", "user_id" : "2", "post_text" : "Hello World 2"}
]
```

I have created a simple html code to output my JSON data

```
<div class="clone_container">

        <div class="clone_div">
        <p class="post_text"></p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

The `<div class="clone_container"></div>` will contain all the postings and the `<div class="clone_div"></div>` will be the div that will be cloned with JSON data.

In order to clone the `<div class="clone_div"></div>` with JSON data, I have created this simple Jquery code:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#clone_btn').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : 'jsonPHP.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success : function(data)
            {
                $.each(data.posts, function(i,data){
                    $('.clone_div').clone().attr('id', ('postId' + data.post_id))
                    .find('.post_text').html(data.post_text).appendTo('.clone_container');
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Now using the above code, I want to clone the `<div class="clone_div"></div>` and add an id to each of the cloned divs by giving the value of the unique post ids. Also I want to output the post text inside each of the '`<p class="post_text"></p>`' tags. The trouble is, instead of cloning the `<div class="clone_div"></div>`, the `<p class="post_text"></p>` is being cloned and appended to the `<div class="clone_container"></div>`. Here's the output I am getting:

```
<div class="clone_container">

    <div class="clone_div">
      <p class="post_text"></p>
    </div>

    <p class="post_text">Hello World 1</p>
    <p class="post_text">Hello World 2</p>

</div>
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are switching from cloned div to p-tag when using `find` method. To switch back to the div itself you can use `.end` method. [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/end/).

```
$('.clone_div:first') //clone only the first div
    .clone()
    .attr('id', ('postId' + data.post_id))
    .find('.post_text')
         .html(data.post_text)
    .end() //sic!
    .appendTo('.clone_container');
```

Comment: @YuriTarabanko, I tried your method by adding the end() command. But now I am getting a new error. Each object in my json array is being multiplied on each output, here's the output I am getting now:
`<div class="clone_container">
  <div class="clone_div" id="postId1">
     <p class="post_text">Hello World1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="clone_div" id="postId2">
     <p class="post_text">Hello World2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="clone_div" id="postId2">
     <p class="post_text">Hello World2</p>
  </div>
</div>`

Comment: @ShahQuadri OIC, you need to clone only the first div actually. :) Not all of them.

Comment: Do you mean the `<div class="clone_container">`?

Comment: Nope the one you are cloning. Every cloned div will match `.clone_div` selector.

Comment: I am sorry, i don't understand your solution. Could please elaborate?

Comment: Which part you don't understand?

Comment: About cloning only the first div and not all of them

Comment: I meant you NEED to clone only the first div matching `.clone_div` selector. Take a look at my answer. Notice I'm using `:first` pseudo-class. `$('.clone_div:first')`

Comment: Thanks man! You saved the day! Problem solved and method understood. :)

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the way you're chaining commands:

See this line:

```
.find('.post_text').html(data.post_text).appendTo('.clone_container');
```

`.find('.post_text').html(data.post_text)` is returning your `<p class='post_text'>` element, which you are then calling appendTo on. You want to instead create a variable of the object returned by this chain: `$('.clone_div').clone().attr('id', ('postId' + data.post_id))` and call appendTo on *that*.

Comment: Hey thanks, your method did help me clone the `.clone_div` instead of the `<p>` but now I am facing a new error. Each object inside my array is multiplying with each iteration. For example, the output that i am getting now is:

`Hello World 1
 Hello World 2
 Hello World 2
 Hello World 3
 Hello World 3
 Hello World 3`

Comment: FYI, the code that I am now using looks like this: 

`$.each(data.posts, function(i,data){
     var row = $('.clone_div').clone().attr('id', ('postId' + data.post_id));
      row.find('.post_text').html(data.post_text);
      row.appendTo('.clone_container');
    });`